# Find items with all modifications successfully completed with multiple entries possible per item

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a query to find all orders that have had all the necessary modifications completed and the work item where the last modification was complete. The table that keeps track of all work done on the order can have multiple entries per item. And no, I unfortunately do not have the ability to modify the schema.

Orders Table:

```
OrderId(int), CustomerId(int), OrderDate(DateTime)  
1, 58, '2021-01-01'
2, 75, '2021-01-01'
3, 78, '2021-01-01'
4, 50, '2021-01-01'
```

Work Table:

```
WorkId(int), OrderId(int), Mod1Completed(bit), Mod2Completed(bit), Mod3Completed(bit), ModDate (DateTime), ModBy (int)
1005, 1, 0, 1, 1, '2021-02-01', 685
1006, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2021-02-03', 875
1007, 2, 0, 1, 0, '2021-02-01', 211
1008, 3, 1, 1, 1, '2021-01-15', 669
```

Sample output:

```
1006, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2021-02-03', 875
1008, 3, 1, 1, 1, '2021-01-15', 669
```

I have the following query that I think is correct (still testing) but it seems clunky and am trying to improve it. For what it's worth, the Work table is regularly purged and would not have massive amounts of data (most likely < 100 rows at any particular time)

```
WITH AnySuccessful AS(
SELECT * FROM Work WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE  Mod1Completed = 1
    OR Mod2Completed = 1
    OR Mod3Completed = 1
),
SuccessfulCount AS(
   SELECT OrderId, 
    MAX(s.ModDate) AS ModDate ,
    Max(CAST(Mod1Completed as int)) + Max(CAST(Mod2Completed as int)) + Max(CAST(Mod3Completed as int)) AS Successes
 FROM AnySuccessful s
 GROUP BY OrderId
),
AllSuccessful AS(
 Select S.OrderId, WorkID, sc.Successes From AnySuccessful S
 Inner Join SuccessfulCount sc on s.OrderId=sc.OrderId and s.ModDate = sc.ModDate AND sc.Successes=3
 )
Select w.* from Work w
 inner join AllSuccessful ASF on  W.OrderId = ASF.OrderId AND W.WorkId = ASF.WorkId
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7d6a/2)

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to follow.. assuming the workid and moddate are always in order

```
select      OrderId
            , max(WorkId)                      as WorkId
            , max(convert(int, Mod1Completed)) as Mod1Completed
            , max(convert(int, Mod2Completed)) as Mod2Completed
            , max(convert(int, Mod3Completed)) as Mod3Completed
            , max(ModDate)                     as ModDate
from        Work
group by    OrderId
having      max(convert(int, Mod1Completed)) + max(convert(int, Mod2Completed)) + max(convert(int, Mod3Completed)) = 3
```

Comment: I'll edit this into the question but that would not work because there could be other entries for work either before or after the entry we want.  Further, I need the actual row from the work table, not the conglomerate data. I left off a little of the work table while anonymizing.  I'll edit the information